# gradle to maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Есть какой-нибудь конвертор gradle файла в maven?

Answer (score 0):

Если следовать инструкциям по [ссылке](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-maven-to-gradle-and-vice-versa#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20Gradle%20to%20Maven,gradle%20file.&text=Then%2C%20simply%20run%20Gradle%20install,and%20the%20directory%20containing%20build.)

> To convert Gradle to Maven, first, Maven plugin need to be added in
> the build.gradle file.

Добавьте мавен плагин в grandle file.

Будет примерно также как посылке

> Then, simply run Gradle install in the directory.
>
> Lastly, simply run gradle install and the directory containing
> build.gradle will do the job. It will create pom-default.xml in the
> build/poms subfolder.

Затем сделайте инсталл. Он создаст pom-default.xml в папке the build/poms

Comment: пробовал я этот способ, у меня выдает :
Cannot publish artifact 'grandl-convert.jar'

Comment: ТОГДА ПО ЭТИМ ИНСТРУКЦИЯМ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html